# got wrong characters encoding using pdfbox to extract text from pdf

Tags: character-encoding, pdfbox

Recently,I have to index pdf into ElasticSearch and using pdfbox to extract text from pdf, however I got wrong characters encoding like this

```
Ýëĭ2ĈjŬj§ė¥ 
1 ŋ?nĳ"2$ 2016£ 2Ú 5Õ,”Òªj§?ně#ĳ"2ě
^ë2ļŘœ A$j§?n 2016£ě#ëÖĭ2Ĉļê    
2 èÅŋ?n$ 2016£ 2Ú 6ÕöĿS¿    ĿS¿ ĿS
Õ¿  ĿSÖ¿  eöĿS&ØºĨĘ
http://www.sse.com.cnLćĈ
A$j§Ýëĭ2ĈŘĐ
```

My code is exactly the same as this page says [here](http://thottingal.in/blog/2009/06/24/pdfbox-extract-text-from-pdf/). I try pdfbox lib version from 0.8.x to 2.0.x, but it still can not work.

Any help or advice will be grateful!

Comment: do you get anything useful with Adobe Reader? Can you share the PDF?

Comment: here is my [pdf](http://111.203.34.66:8443/mnt/storage/stock/2016/02/24/e2a9227a3565f947271244ef2716ae09483a6559.pdf).Have u any documents about how to shoot this problem with Adobe Reader?

Comment: I don't get anything with Adobe Reader either, except a few "2016". See https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/faq.html#notext and the answer below too.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I find my answer, thanks so much!

Comment: please answer the question yourself, or delete it, so that there are no "orphans" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer from @Tilman comment.

> See pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/faq.html#notext and the answer below too.

Comment: It's better to add some text instead of a link-only answer.